# How to filter defects that are linked to test instances with 'blocked' status in Quality Centre

Tags: quality-center

I need to generate a report from the dashboard view of Quality Center to get all the blocking defects in my test sets. Meaning, I want to filter the list of defects that are linked to test instances marked with the status 'blocked.

Could you please help me in generating such custom report?

Thanks,
Karim.

Comment: What test tool are you using?

Answer (score 1):

To list out the defects and the corresponding test cases that blocked, its very easy to generate using Excel query feature in Quality center. The query has to join test instance, tests and link table to retrieve the details. The query looks like this

```
SELECT T.TS_NAME, TC.TC_TEST_INSTANCE, LN_BUG_ID
  FROM TEST T, TESTCYCL TC, LINK L
 WHERE     T.TS_TEST_ID = TC.TC_TEST_ID -- Condition joining TEST (testcases) and TESTCYCL (Test instances) table
       AND L.LN_ENTITY_TYPE = 'TESTCYCL' -- This condition makes sure that defects linked to test instaces only need to retrieved
       AND TC.TC_TESTCYCL_ID = L.LN_ENTITY_ID -- Condition to join LINK and TESTCYCL table
       AND TC.TC_STATUS = 'BLOCKED'
```

For more details and different SQL queries that help you play with information you want extract [refer this blog link.](http://qtp-automate.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/quality-center-test-instances-test.html)

Comment: The above query worked but unable to fetch complete blocked testcase...total count is 27 but it pull only 9 blocked TC .
Could you please help me whether iam folowing the correct steps: 1. logged in QC 2. click on Dash Board 3. Click on Private/Publci 4. Create a xls doc 5. Located on Desktop 6. Click on Query builder & Pasted the above SQL Query 7. Run the Query 8. Able to xls report but only 9 are pulled

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
SELECT
C.CY_CYCLE 'TestSet Name',/*Test Set.Name*/
T.TS_NAME 'Test Name',
T.TS_EXEC_STATUS 'Status',
TC.TC_TEST_INSTANCE 'Test Instance',
L.LN_BUG_ID 'defect id'

FROM TEST T, TESTCYCL TC, LINK L , CYCLE C

WHERE
       T.TS_TEST_ID = TC.TC_TEST_ID -- Condition joining TEST (testcases) and TESTCYCL (Test instances) table
       AND C.CY_CYCLE_ID = TC.TC_CYCLE_ID /*-- Condition joining TEST (testcases) and TESTCYCL (Test instances) table */
       AND L.LN_ENTITY_TYPE = 'TESTCYCL' -- This condition makes sure that defects linked to test instaces only need to retrieved
       AND TC.TC_TESTCYCL_ID = L.LN_ENTITY_ID -- Condition to join LINK and TESTCYCL table
```